# Issue with Seaborn Box Plot Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, boxplot

I plotted a Box plot using seaborn.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(4,10)})
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Calibri"  
my_pal = {"Track_Angle_Ctrl": "limegreen", "Track_Angle_KO": "#FF4500"}
ax = sns.boxplot(data = Track_Angle, palette = my_pal, linewidth=2.5)
plt.title('TRACK ANGLE BOX PLOT DISTRIBUTION',fontsize = "20", pad = 20, fontweight = "bold")
plt.xlabel("TRACKS", fontsize = "20", labelpad = 20)
plt.ylabel("TRACK ANGLE IN DEGREES", fontsize = "20", labelpad = 20)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=18)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=18)
ax.set_xticklabels(['Ctrl','Knock-Out'])
plt.legend(labels= ["Ctrl", "Knock-out"], fontsize = 18, loc = (1.04,0.85))
plt.grid(True)
```

[image: Seaborn Box Plot]

For some reason the legend on top right does not show the labels correctly. As you can see in the legend, the box is shown correctly for Ctrl but not for Knock-out.

Sample:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(8,10)})
sns.set_theme(style="ticks")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
plt.title('TRACK ANGLE BOX PLOT DISTRIBUTION',fontsize = "20", pad = 20, 
fontweight = "bold")
plt.xlabel("TRACKS", fontsize = "20", labelpad = 20)
plt.ylabel("TRACK ANGLE IN DEGREES", fontsize = "20", labelpad = 20)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=18)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=18)
ax.set_xticklabels(['1','2','3','4'])
plt.legend(labels= ["1", "2","3","4"], fontsize = 18, loc = (1.44,0.85))
plt.grid(True)
```

[image: Sample]

Why here also only the 1st legend shows box and rest three show only a line. I require boxes in legend for every label 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: You can also do `ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue='day', data=tips, dodge=False)` use the category column as both `x` and `hue`.

Comment: Instead of `plt.legend()`, for most seaborn plots `sns.move_legend()` works better.

Comment: Position of legend is not an issue. The issue is the legend structure where green box respective to '1' is shown and not for every other data. (2, 3, 4 should shows boxes instead of lines in the legend).

Comment: The issue with the legend patches should be resolved by instead plotting with the method in the first comment. Use hue=

Comment: Did you solve it @PrateekSinha? I am also having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding hue worked for me:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df.head()

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(4,10)})
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.boxplot(data = df, x = "sex", y = "total_bill", hue = "sex", linewidth=2.5)

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0), loc='lower left', borderaxespad=0)
```

[image: boxplot]